# Combine Matrices row-wise by weighting them in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have **N** matrices with dimensions  **R** x **R** and one 'Weight matrix' with dimension **R** x **N**. 
Now I want to combine those **N** matrices row-wise by weighting them with the 'Weight matrix'. In the end I want a  **R** x **R** matrix.

Let me show you an example:
In the following example my initial matrices are a and b and my weight matrix is c. The desired output is matrix r.

The first row of r is the first row of a, because c[0,0] is 1 and c[0,1] is 0, so we just consider the first row of matrix a.

The second row of r is a weighted average of row 2 from both matrix a and b (because c[1,0]= 0.5 and c[1,1] = 0.5).

The third row of r is the third row of b, because c[2,0] is 0 and c[2,1] is 1, so we just consider the third row of matrix b.

[image: Example]

How can I do this in Python (preferable with a numpy function)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
In [57]: A # 3D input array
Out[57]: 
array([[[0.2, 0. , 0.8],
        [0. , 0. , 1. ],
        [0. , 0.2, 0.8]],

       [[1. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0.2, 0.8],
        [0.2, 0. , 0.8]]])

In [58]: c # 2D weight array
Out[58]: 
array([[1. , 0. ],
       [0.5, 0.5],
       [0. , 1. ]])

In [59]: np.einsum('ijk,ji->jk',A,c)
Out[59]: 
array([[0.2, 0. , 0.8],
       [0. , 0.1, 0.9],
       [0.2, 0. , 0.8]])
```

Alternatively with `np.matmul` -

```
In [142]: (np.matmul(A.transpose(1,2,0),c[...,None]))[...,0]
Out[142]: 
array([[0.2, 0. , 0.8],
       [0. , 0.1, 0.9],
       [0.2, 0. , 0.8]])
```

Note : On Python 3.x `np.matmul` could be replaced by `@ operator`.